# vector by reference in a struct?

Tags: c++, vector, struct

I want to create a struct containing a double and a vector of strings. I tried this

```
int main ()
{   
  struct List
  {
      double price;
      vector<string> items;
  };

  List list;

  ifstream infile ("Aap.txt");

  double p;
  infile>>p;
  list.price=p;
  cout<<list.price<<endl;

  int i=0;
  string name;
  getline(infile,name);

  while(infile)
  {
      list.items.push_back(name);
      cout<<list.items[i]<<endl;
      i++;
      getline(infile,name);
  }
  infile.close();

  if (!infile)
  {
      cout<<"File closed."<<endl;
  }

return 0;
```

This is not filling my vector, because it is not by reference in the struct I suppose?

But when I define the vector in the struct as:

```
vector<string>& items;
```

I get an error saying:

error: structure `list' with uninitialized reference members.

How can I fix this?

Thank you for helping!

Comment: What does "not filling my vector" mean? Your code looks fine as far as that `vector` is concerned. No need for any references.

Comment: It means that the code 'couts' the double from the file, but not the list of items...

Comment: I just tried your code with a quick artificial input file and it works fine. What does your input file look like? Does it read and print the price value in your experiments?

Comment: Are you sure you don't have a `using namespace std;` somewhere? A variable named list could easily conflict with the list type that is declared in the standard namespace.

Comment: Oh my... I changed somethings to make the code clearer for posting... copy-paste in code blocks.. it now runs fine :-)

Answer (score 0):

Your code works perfectly fine.

There's a little issue of the first read: if you have a newline character in your input file after the price value, that newline character will remain unread. In this situation the first call to `getline` will read an empty string, meaning that the first name in your `items` array will end up empty.